# Show info window marker when click from outside map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have designed for map like code below

```
 <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%;" id="loctable">
      <th> List Location</th>
         <tbody id="maploc">

         </tbody>
  </table>
         
  <div id="map"></div>
```

So in `List Location` is only list `location name` that I get from response api json. And I show `marker` on `div` `map` with data `latitude` and `longitude` I get from same response api json

Here's the code to show list `location name`

```
//response from json, data existing
var exist = [{"id":"001",
              "location":"mysql",
              "geolocation":{
                  "lat":"-6.146627155693579",
                  "long":"106.76637134201562"
             }}, 
             {"id":"002",
              "location":"golang",
              "geolocation":{
                  "lat":"-6.134509125934106",
                  "long":"106.73478564865624"
             }}] 

for (var i = 0; i < exist.length; i++) 
{
    var latz = exist[i].geolocation.lat;
    var longz = exist[i].geolocation.long;
    var ids = exist[i].id;
    var location = exist[i].location;
                 
    var mark = '<tr>'+
                        '<td><img src="<?= base_url(); ?>assets/addon-media/red-marker.png">'+
                               location+
                        '</td>'+
                    '</tr>';

    $('#maploc').append(mark);

    //show marker
}
```

And here is code to draw marker on map based on same response api

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(latz, longz),
        map: map,
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    
    const contentString =
                    '<div class="card card-custom card-stretch gutter-b location">'+
                        '<div class="card-body d-flex flex-column" id="locationCard" style="padding:5px 0px;">'+
                            '<div class="flex-grow-1 pb-5 align-items-center row">'+
                                '<div class="col-md-6" style="display: table-cell">'+
                                    '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">'+
                                        '<div class="text-muted mt-1">Location</div>'+
                                        '<p class="text-dark font-weight-bolder font-size-lg mt-2">'+location+'</p>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString,
        maxWidth: 400,
        maxHeight: 350
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,contentString,infowindow){ 
           return function() {
               infowindow.setContent(contentString);
               infowindow.open(map,marker);
           };
    })(marker,contentString,infowindow));
```

I want to ask how can I make when user click one of location in `List Location` table, the `marker` in `map` will be show `infowindow` based on location clicked ?

Right now, to show `infowindow`, you must click marker on the map

Thank you

Comment: See the example from Mike Williams' (v2) tutorial: [The Basics - Part 2: Adding a clickable sidebar](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic2.htm).  [Translated to v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html)

Comment: If that doesn't help, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue, the code snippets provided in the question do not work (the latitude/longitude values are not valid for one).

Comment: Hi @geocodezip, it still doesn't help, I'm still confused to take the example on my code

Comment: I've updated the code too, now lat/long values are true

Comment: You still haven't provided a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. put all the code in the loop that processes the JSON
2. keep references to the markers you create (in the code below, the `markers` array).

```
//response from json, data existing
var exist = [{"id":"001",
              "location":"mysql",
              "geolocation":{
                  "lat":"-6.146627155693579",
                  "long":"106.76637134201562"
             }}, 
             {"id":"002",
              "location":"golang",
              "geolocation":{
                  "lat":"-6.134509125934106",
                  "long":"106.73478564865624"
             }}]
  for (var i = 0; i < exist.length; i++) {
    var latz = exist[i].geolocation.lat;
    var longz = exist[i].geolocation.long;
    var ids = exist[i].id;
    var location = exist[i].location;
    let markerNum = markers.length;
    var mark = '<tr>' +
      '<td><img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"><a href="javascript:myclick(' + (markerNum) + ')">' +
      location +
      '<\/a></td>' +
      '</tr>';

    $('#maploc').append(mark);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(latz, longz),
      map: map,
      icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"
    });
    marker.setMap(map);

    const contentString =
      '<div class="card card-custom card-stretch gutter-b location">' +
      '<div class="card-body d-flex flex-column" id="locationCard" style="padding:5px 0px;">' +
      '<div class="flex-grow-1 pb-5 align-items-center row">' +
      '<div class="col-md-6" style="display: table-cell">' +
      '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">' +
      '<div class="text-muted mt-1">Location</div>' +
      '<p class="text-dark font-weight-bolder font-size-lg mt-2">' + location + '<\/a></p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400,
      maxHeight: 350
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, contentString, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, contentString, infowindow));
    markers.push(marker);
  }
```

3. add a `myclick` function to open the marker by index in the array (from the [Mike Williams' (v2) tutorial example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic2.htm), [translated to v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html), slightly modified)

```
// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(markerNum) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/89b7sr62/2/)

[image: screenshot of map after clicking on "sidebar"]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;
let markers = [];
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  //response from json, data existing
var exist = [{"id":"001",
              "location":"mysql",
              "geolocation":{
                  "lat":"-6.146627155693579",
                  "long":"106.76637134201562"
             }}, 
             {"id":"002",
              "location":"golang",
              "geolocation":{
                  "lat":"-6.134509125934106",
                  "long":"106.73478564865624"
             }}]
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < exist.length; i++) {
    var latz = exist[i].geolocation.lat;
    var longz = exist[i].geolocation.long;
    var ids = exist[i].id;
    var location = exist[i].location;
    let markerNum = markers.length;
    var mark = '<tr>' +
      '<td><img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"><a href="javascript:myclick(' + (markerNum) + ')">' +
      location +
      '<\/a></td>' +
      '</tr>';

    $('#maploc').append(mark);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(latz, longz),
      map: map,
      icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

    const contentString =
      '<div class="card card-custom card-stretch gutter-b location">' +
      '<div class="card-body d-flex flex-column" id="locationCard" style="padding:5px 0px;">' +
      '<div class="flex-grow-1 pb-5 align-items-center row">' +
      '<div class="col-md-6" style="display: table-cell">' +
      '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-xl-12">' +
      '<div class="text-muted mt-1">Location</div>' +
      '<p class="text-dark font-weight-bolder font-size-lg mt-2">' + location + '</p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';

    const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString,
      maxWidth: 400,
      maxHeight: 350
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, contentString, infowindow) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      };
    })(marker, contentString, infowindow));
    markers.push(marker);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
function myclick(markerNum) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 80%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:100%;" id="loctable">
    <th> List Location</th>
    <tbody id="maploc">

    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67292812/show-info-window-marker-when-click-from-outside-map# src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```